# Why can't we take the surface as part of a system when conserving linear momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, friction

In a problem I'm facing, friction acts on the system that I wish to apply conservation of linear momentum. Why can't I take the surface as a part of system and conserve momentum? As the surface is basically earth, as it's mass is so huge it's velocity change is negligible and I can cancel it's momentum on $LHS$ and $RHS$ when I write $P_i=P_f$. Could someone please help me understand why it's wrong to do so?

Comment: A little problem is that we can see experimentaly that $P_i \neq P_f$

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I take the surface as a part of system and conserve momentum?

Technically, you can.  Experimentally, this will be difficult.

> As the surface is basically earth, as it's mass is so huge it's velocity change is negligible and I can cancel it's momentum on  and  when I write =.

Its velocity change is indeed negligible (and in fact, I would say impossible to measure with any tools you have).  But when multiplied by the mass of the earth, this negligible $\Delta v$ will turn out to be a significant $\Delta p$.  You cannot assume the momentum is equal just because the change in velocity is minuscule.

Comment: Oh so you are saying the momentum value will be huge even though the velocity change is very small? Won't it be like multiplying a huge quantity with a number that is very close to zero? Dosent the product i.e momentum tends to zero?